# Is there an idiom, proverb or a saying about someone who receives all benefits and good things while complaining about it?

Tags: idiom-requests, proverb-requests

For example: Someone who has a tree that gives him fruits, he doesn't take care of it or have to take care of that tree.
He eats all the fruits of that tree, and yet he dares to find or come up with something to complain about with regards to that tree (sort of blaming the tree).

Comment: Like "biting the hand that feeds you"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would you call it when somebody complains about something that is given to them?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/363211/what-would-you-call-it-when-somebody-complains-about-something-that-is-given-to): 'biting the hand that feeds you' / 'looking a gift horse in the mouth'

Comment: biting the hand that feeds you is more of causing harm to someone in return to their good did, but not this what I'm looking for.
there is no harm in the example I sited. thank you very much for your suggestion

Comment: No, it doesn't actually mean "biting a hand"...it means to disrespect, be ungrateful, or criticize the giver, exactly what you asked for.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but it's not exactly what I asked for. I know  the meaning of "biting the hand that feeds you", opposite to what you assumed I didn't think that means physically do the act of biting. this proverb means that a first part that have been doing good things and helps a second part, but after all that good things the second part returns bad acts and words in exchange, and this might end everything.
this requires a direct relation between this two parts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the word for someone who doesn't appreciate what he has and wants more?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395629/whats-the-word-for-someone-who-doesnt-appreciate-what-he-has-and-wants-more) Also [What do you call a person who is never content with anything that is given to him?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192521/) and [A single word for someone who is not pleased no matter how hard you try,](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31221/) among others.

Comment: my request is about a direct or indirect relation and  I put the tree example in purpose,
the tree does not know that it's doing good things for the person who eats its fruits, the tree is continuing growing without realizing anything, but in real life the person is benefiting from the tree, but he is blaming the tree for the fruit shape or taste even though he getting it for free and effortless. the relation between the person and the tree continues like that. the relation does not end. the complaining and blaming doesn't reach the tree but it continues.
I hope this helps.

Comment: FumbleFingers
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31221/
this one 90% of what I'm looking for, is there a proverb or idiom for that.
like inplacable person that complains about you not trying hard when you tried the hardest you can.

Comment: "**Much wants more**" is what I hear. ++  “If she would only sell the hut. and give the money to us.” said she. “Then we could build a new house.” == “Much wants more!” answered Lars Peter smilingly. In his opinion the house they lived in was quite good enough." ++ From “*Ditte Everywoman (Girl Alive. Daughter of Man. Toward the Stars.)* By Martin Andersen Nexo